# How to detect and stop an infinite loop in user-provided JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, editor, infinite-loop

I am writing an in-browser code editor for games. The editor will allow users to write their own JavaScript files, which are then loaded into the same DOM that the editor is running on. This will allow them to see the game in a canvas element next to the code and update it every time they save.

The editor is aimed at people who are new to JavaSript, and it can be easy to accidentally get an infinite loop. If possible, I want to set up my editor such that if a loop executes too many times or too fast, the loop is broken and a message pops up alerting the user that they have an infinite loop.

This would be ideal for people who are new, because if the entire editor just crashed suddenly, they may not realize what their mistake was and think it was an issue with my editor.

How can I implement fail-safes in my editor which stop infinite loops automatically?

Comment: @user2182349 The editor will allow users to write their own javascript files, which are then loaded into the same DOM that the editor is running on. This will allow them to see the game in a canvas element next to the code and update it every time they save.

Comment: [Here's what CodePen does](https://codepen.io/quezo/post/stopping-infinite-loops) to stop infinite loops. It pre-compiles the JavaScript to insert monitoring functions inside all loops and functions.

Comment: my question is if i can somehow watch any loops that the user creates, or somehow inject some code that would break and alert that an infinite loop is happening.

Comment: @4castle that's perfect, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. This is my first question on here so I'm not 100% sure how it works, but if you add this as an answer I will mark it as solved! Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to put the code in the same DOM. In fact I don't recommend that since you'll have conflicts with names etc. If the user types `window.document = null` your editor will stop working. It's pretty easy to use a blob. `someIFrame.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'}));`

Comment: I would answer, but I'd basically just be quoting the article, because I know nothing about how it's implemented besides what's in the article. Perhaps someone else may know more, and can write a decent answer.

Comment: @4castle, Posting your comment as an answer and linking to the article is fine. It's also probably more helpful for other people looking for answers.

Comment: @gman, That's a very good point, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle potential infinite loops in user-submitted code is to pre-compile the code to insert monitoring functions inside the code. This is known as **instrumenting**, and is [explained in detail by Codepen](https://codepen.io/quezo/post/stopping-infinite-loops).

For example, the following code from a user...:

```js
for (var i = 0;; i++) {
  console.log("hello for loop.");
}

console.log("We'll never reach this line of code");
```

...would be instrumented like so:

```js
for (var i = 0;; i++) {
    if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
        break;
    }
    console.log('hello for loop.');
}

console.log('finished because we broke out of the loop');
```

Comment: window.CP is part of CodePen to prevent infinite loops from hanging your tab or browser. It is better to write the basic logic of the function which can be used to prevent infinite loop